SwiftData relationships between elements of the same model - can you control or suppress them?
Part of my app involves a genogram (basically a family tree of genetic relations). That means I really only have 1 model type - a Relative, who has relation types to the person at the core of the tree (the "index" person). I've settled on a model of having each person defining their nuclear family (parents, siblings, children, and spouse(s)), in addition to their relation to the index. This would allow the tree to be drawn (when I get that far) by traversing the relationships, and gives an easy way for the user to verify things. It seems necessary to do this way because I don't just need to know Person B is the aunt of Index, I need to know how - Person B is sister of Person A who is father to index, etc.
Issues
I can't properly define inverse relationships, because there's only 1 model - inverse of siblings is siblings, which creates a circular reference. Same for spouses. Inverse of both mom and dad is children - but if you tell SwiftData that, then when you add Parent A is mom of Index, Parent A also gets added as dad.
I left off the relationships and tried to add everything in my savePerson method, and have it add the relationship, the inverse, and other things it can already guess. For example, if you add mom first, then when you add dad to index person, it will automatically put mom and dad as spouses. Then add a sibling to index, and it will also make that person child of mom and dad.
This all looks like it works! Run the app, add a bunch of people, all relations are added as they should be, with the program making assumptions/guesses where appropriate.
But after closing the app and reopening, some relationships are missing.
Examples:

Add Index, then Mom -> Mom and Index are properly inverses of each other and persist on opening/closing; then add Dad and check Mom/Dad are spouses and Index is child of both -> however, on reopening, Mom suddenly has no children


same happens in opposite direction - add Dad first and then Mom and everything works, but reopen and Dad will lose Index


Add Mom, Dad, Sister, then Dad's brother and sister as Aunt and Uncle -> again, you can verify that all relationships work correctly at first -> on reopening, Dad has no siblings, one of Aunt or Uncle has one, the other has (correctly) 2

Forcing modelContext.save() after the savePerson method didn't help, or surface the bug before reopening. I assume something is happening in SwiftData "correcting" what it thinks the relationships should be - if it were an error in my code itself, I assume I'd see a problem immediately, not on restart? I don't manipulate the save data on close or restart of the app (at least not deliberately).
Of note, I also tried to re-jig the savePerson method a few ways to do things in a different order, add relationships from only one side (see if the other side would be assumed by SwiftData), etc. - all attempts either caused crashes (I think for invalid inverse relationships) or just led to the same error where things get dropped on restart. Changing where I call modelContext.insert also didn't matter.
So if SwiftData's assumptions are causing the issue, is there a proper way to define the necessary relationships when I have only this 1 model? Or stop SwiftData from doing its thing so I can control all relationships manually?
Model and enums
@Model
class Relative {
    let name: String
    let gender: Gender
    let dob: Date
    let isIndex: Bool
    let relationToIndex: RelationType
    var qualifier: RelationQualifier?
    var diagnoses: [String] = []
    var mother: Relative? = nil
    var father: Relative? = nil
    var spouses: [Relative] = []
    var siblings: [Relative] = []
    var children: [Relative] = []
    
    init(name: String, gender: Gender, dob: Date, isIndex: Bool = false, relationToIndex: RelationType, qualifier: RelationQualifier? = nil, diagnoses: [String] = [], mother: Relative? = nil, father: Relative? = nil, spouses: [Relative] = [], siblings: [Relative] = [], children: [Relative] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.dob = dob
        self.isIndex = isIndex
        self.relationToIndex = relationToIndex
        self.qualifier = qualifier
        self.diagnoses = diagnoses
        self.mother = mother
        self.father = father
        self.spouses = spouses
        self.siblings = siblings
        self.children = children
    }
}

enum Gender: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case male = "Male"
    case female = "Female"
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

enum RelationType: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case undefined = "N/A"
    case index = "Index"
    case mother = "Mother"
    case father = "Father"
    case brother = "Brother"
    case sister = "Sister"
    case brotherInLaw = "Brother-in-law"
    case sisterInLaw = "Sister-in-law"
    case son = "Son"
    case daughter = "Daughter"
    case sonInLaw = "Son-in-law"
    case daughterInLaw = "Daughter-in-law"
    case grandson = "Grandson"
    case granddaughter = "Granddaughter"
    case husband = "Husband"
    case wife = "Wife"
    case aunt = "Aunt"
    case uncle = "Uncle"
    case cousin = "Cousin"
    case grandmother = "Grandmother"
    case grandfather = "Grandfather"
    case niece = "Niece"
    case nephew = "Nephew"
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

enum PrimaryRelationType: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case parent = "Parent"
    case sibling = "Sibling"
    case spouse = "Spouse"
    case child = "Child"
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

enum RelationQualifier: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case none = "None"
    case grand = "Grand"
    case great = "Great"
    case step = "Step"
    case half = "Half"
    case first = "First"
    case second = "Second"
    case third = "Third"
    case fourth = "Fourth"
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

Primary method in question
    func savePerson() {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: dob)
        let newDate = Date.from(year: components.year!, month: components.month!, day: components.day!)
        
        let newRelative = Relative(name: name, gender: gender, dob: newDate, relationToIndex: relation, diagnoses: diagnoses)
        
        
        let relativeToAddTo: Relative
        if self.relativeToAddTo != nil {
            relativeToAddTo = self.relativeToAddTo!
        } else {
            relativeToAddTo = self.index
        }
        
        
        if relativeToAdd == .child {
            if relativeToAddTo.gender == .female {
                newRelative.mother = relativeToAddTo
                //copy father from the last spouse of origin relative
                if let father = relativeToAddTo.spouses.last {
                    newRelative.father = father
                }
            } else {
                newRelative.father = relativeToAddTo
                if let mother = relativeToAddTo.spouses.last {
                    newRelative.mother = mother
                }
            }
            //origin parent's kids are new entry's siblings
            newRelative.siblings += relativeToAddTo.children
            //add reciprocal children/siblings
            for child in relativeToAddTo.children {
                child.siblings.append(newRelative)
            }
            //add this child now to the parent
            relativeToAddTo.children.append(newRelative)
        } else if relativeToAdd == .parent {
            newRelative.children.append(relativeToAddTo)
            if gender == .female {
                relativeToAddTo.mother = newRelative
                //add origin relative's father; we shouldn't need to check if there already is one, because this relative is new, so [spouses] is empty
                if let father = relativeToAddTo.father {
                    newRelative.spouses.append(father)
                    //if the father exists, this new relative is a spouse
                    father.spouses.append(newRelative)
                }
            } else if gender == .male {
                relativeToAddTo.father = newRelative
                //add mother, if she exists
                if let mother = relativeToAddTo.mother {
                    newRelative.spouses.append(mother)
                    //and reciprocate
                    mother.spouses.append(newRelative)
                }
            }
            //origin child's siblings are the new relative's children
            newRelative.children += relativeToAddTo.siblings
        } else if relativeToAdd == .sibling {
            //copy any siblings that already exist
            newRelative.siblings += relativeToAddTo.siblings
            //also add this person to those siblings' lists
            for sibling in relativeToAddTo.siblings {
                sibling.siblings.append(newRelative)
            }
            //then, add the new relative as a sibling, and reciprocal
            newRelative.siblings.append(relativeToAddTo)
            relativeToAddTo.siblings.append(newRelative)
            //siblings can be assumed to share parents
            if let mother = relativeToAddTo.mother {
                newRelative.mother = mother
            }
            if let father = relativeToAddTo.father {
                newRelative.father = father
            }
        } else if relativeToAdd == .spouse {
            newRelative.spouses.append(relativeToAddTo)
            relativeToAddTo.spouses.append(newRelative)
            //nothing further to do
            //spouses can't be assumed to share kids
            //we don't know which marriage each child came from
            //user must manually fix this
        }
        
        modelContext.insert(newRelative)

        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch(let error) {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        dismiss()
    }


I believe you have too many relationships properties in your model. Why do you need relationships for siblings, this is implied by sharing the same parents? Also the RelationType is a strange type, in many ways it also contains redundant information. Note that I didn’t read all of the very long text so I focused on the strange model rather than the actual issue but I assume they are dependent.

@JoakimDanielson: Siblings do not always share parents - half-siblings are genetically related, without having both of the same parents. RelationType is the relation to the Index person, whereas the rest has to do with the nuclear family of the particular Relative. It may be possible to remove, but other parts of the program work better with that info rather than "calculating" the relation to Index each time.

Right, siblings don’t always share the same parents which can be deduced from comparing their mother and father properties.

Maybe you would be better of splitting people and their relationships in two different model or split it into biological and legal relationships, I don’t have a clear solution but I feel the current solution looks to complicated and not very flexible.

@JoakimDanielson I don't get how splitting Relative into Person and Relations helps - I still need the same properties (nearly, if I can work around deleting siblings, like you suggested). Relations becomes a pseudo-dictionary and I'm juggling the same data across 2 models instead of 1, which actually seems more complicated, or at least more typing when I keep calling person.relations.xxx. Also, the relationship/inverse issue doesn't change, it just moves to a different model. Despite my doubts, I made a whole new version with the split you suggest and can confirm I got the exact same bug.

I stated that I didn’t have a clear solution but even if that suggestion didn’t work I still think you need a different design. After I wrote my comment I took a look at your second part of the code you posted and it contains to many unknowns to be fully understood and it can’t be used to reproduce the problem .

Another path to take is to first implement a simpler solution and then add properties and functionality when the base implementation works, like removing anything related to this index functionality and also remove the RelationType property and related stuff so all you really have is an app for creating and relating parents and children.

@JoakimDanielson As in the original post, there were issues even when only using parents/children. Still, I started from scratch with just parents (no mother/father separation) and children, and still got the same error. What did you have trouble with in the posted code? It's just meant to use the type of relative being added to assume relationships and set them. I think the issue is that I have a Model with relationships to members of the same Model... SwiftData seems to override what I'm setting manually, and I need to control that.

I tried moving to CoreData. I got the same bug, but more errors which confirmed the issue is the lack of inverse relationships. I went back to @JoakimDanielson suggestions and ended up with a model that allows Person objects to exist inside NuclearFamily objects that contain parents and children, with inverses. More complex model, simpler code, but I still have to figure out how to traverse the tree when made of smaller families. I'm leaving the question up for now - CoreData said it was not advised, but not impossible to lack inverses, so it should still be possible without this workaround.

In iOS18 Beta you can specify nil for an inverse relationship to indicate it is one-way only. Might suit your needs?

@RedNightingale I'm don't have any of the beta software, so I can't try this for a few months, but my suspicion is that it won't work. CoreData already allows nil relationships and it didn't work there, it just gave a warning and then produced the same bug. There's some magic needed that Apple doesn't define for us.
