SwiftData Models loses the relationship after the app closes and relaunches
We have an app that uses two SwiftData models in a one-to-many relationship to Log Data given by the user. In the first model we have a  date property and an array. Yhe other model is using the one to many relationship
@Model
class  firstModel {
var timeStamp:Date
@Relationship(inverse:\\SecondModel.firstModel)var firstmodels:\[FirstModel\] = \[\]

    init(timeStamp: Date) {
        self.timeStamp = timeStamp
    }

}

@Model
class SecondModel {
var name:String
var amount:Double
var firstModel:FirstModel?

    init(name: String, amount: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }   

}

We have one view that Inserts the properties in the of the FirstViewModel and pulls data from the SecondViewModel and if it is emtpy it creates some data we selected the data and returns them in the FirstViewModel  where we inserted the data. The problem occurs when we create at least one more record and present them in a List. We added again the date and use the same data we created in the SecondViewModel. The List of the FirstViewModel updates correctly and has two different dates with the same data. But when we close the app and reopen it , the data from the SecondViewModel only appears in the latest entry.
Every example that has to do with one to many relationship in SwiftData shows that we first create data for the first model and then we update the data by inserting the data from the second model. In ourt example we createData for the first model and add some data from the second. We present them in a List and everything seem to work fine. But when we close and reopen the app the data from the second model appears in the latest entry of the first model only.
the view that we add the  firstModel with it's only property that is a Date. and within this View we pass the secondModelView where we select them from a list and return them selected:

struct AddFirstModel: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @State private var date:Date = .now
    @State private var showAddSecondModel = false
    @Query private var secondModels:[SecondModel]
    @State private var secondModelAdded:[SecondModel] = []
    
//    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("When")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(date.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("SecondModels")
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        showAddSecondModel.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    })
                }
                if secondModels.isEmpty {
                    ContentUnavailableView("You need to add data for your secondModel", systemImage: "pencil")
                    
                } else {
                    List(secondModelAdded) { model in

                            Text(model.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddSecondModel) {
                SecondModelListView(secondModels: secondModels, selectedModels: $secondModelAdded)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        if !secondModelAdded.isEmpty {
                            var  newFirstModel = FirstModel(timeStamp: date)
                            for secmod in secondModelAdded  {
                                print(secmod.name)
                                newFirstModel.secondModels.append(secmod)
                            }
                            context.insert(newFirstModel)
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


and the SecondModelListView where we select the data(name,amount)  that are connected with the relatioShip one to one and return to the AddFirstModelView :

struct SecondModelListView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    let secondModels:[SecondModel]
    @State private var createnewSecondModel = false
    @State private var selectedNewModel: Bool = false
    @Binding var selectedModels:[SecondModel]
  
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List(secondModels) {secondModel in
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                           addOrRemoveItem(secondModel)
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName:selectedModels.contains(secondModel) ? "circle.fill" :  "circle" )
                        })
                        SecondModelListRowView(secondModel: secondModel)
                    }
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("SecondModels List")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                        Button {
                            createnewSecondModel.toggle()
                        }label: {
                            Text("Add")
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Done") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $createnewSecondModel) {
                    AddSecondModelview()
                        .presentationDetents([.medium])
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    func addOrRemoveItem(_ secondModel: SecondModel) {
            if let index = selectedModels.firstIndex(of: secondModel) {
                selectedModels.remove(at: index)
            } else {
                selectedModels.append(secondModel)
            }
        }
}

the AddSecondModelView where we add objects to the SecondModel :

struct AddSecondModelView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context


   
    @State private var name:String = ""
    @State private var amount:String = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

                TextField("Amount", text: $amount)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Save") {
                            guard !name.isEmpty  else {return}
                            guard let amount = Double(amount) else {return}
                            let secondModel = SecondModel(name: name, amount: amount)
                            context.insert(secondModel)
                            dismiss()
                        }
                        
                    }

                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



also this is how the list of FirstModels Look when i add multiple entries with the same secondModels 

[FirstModelListView before closing the app][1]


and this how it looks when i close and reopen the app

[FirstModelListView after closing and reopening the app][2]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/4hTbM6qL.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/OlrQiS81.png


Please add the code where you actually create the objects and set their values, specially the relationship properties.

Since this is my first time as a stack Overflow user forgive me for my mistakes as i reproduce the issue –

You added a lot of code and for some reason you have omitted most of the view names so it's not easy to follow the logic of the code. So without the risk of having misunderstood the code I. have to ask why you are not passing the FirstModel object a new SecondModel object is the child of to the view where you create the SecondModel objects? If possible try to clean up your code and only include what is really relevant to the question

I have cleaned and uploaded it again.

This seems similar to a question I asked about a week ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78645323/swiftdata-relationships-between-elements-of-the-same-model-can-you-control-or). I thought my issue was having a model with relationships back to the same model (as opposed to 2 models like yours). But the outcome was the same - SwiftData will drop some relationships when I close and restart the app. Have you ever tried adding multiple pieces of data at once, and seen a pattern in what's kept/dropped, or are you only ever adding one firstModel and one secondModel in your examples?

No only one relationship. But whatever video tutorial I have seen, always you create the first model and when you update it then you add data from the second model. My problem is that I want them to be created at the same time. This only happens when I create and input data to the first from the second model. Or is this irrelevant?

Without knowing what your AddSecondModelView and ContentView look like, it's a bit hard to follow what's going wrong - you say your issue is in adding the data but we don't have some of the details or methods telling us how it's being added. Also, is AddFirstModel view a sheet? But SecondModelListView is also a sheet, attaching to the first?

Also, can you include which tutorials you were following so we can see how your code differs from their examples?

I have uploaded the part that where new Second Models are added. And yes, AddFirtstModel View is presented as a sheet and also the SecondModelListView also is presented as a sheet. I know that this isn't the best way, but I made it very simple so that I can find the bug and refactor it later. I haven't seen any tutorials regarding my example. Likewise, I have seen other tutorials where the First Model is created and then is edited and attach  the SecondModel  instead of i want it to be done when i create the FirstModel  and add the same time the secondModel.

The code you've presented is incorrect - it's not possible to get the output you show in those pictures. I think you made multiple errors in copying the code here, but one of the biggest is addOrRemoveItem in SecondModelListView. It's only called when a button is clicked, but the button is inside of a List row. Those rows are based on the secondModel array, which has to be passed from a different view, from the SecondModels attached to a FirstModel instance - which can't exist until you've saved one first. So basically, SecondModel objects are never saved in your example.

if you want i can send you the sample project so that you can understand
